# Searching a char* for a member of char* array in c

Tags: c

I've been a little stuck on searching through strings to find if a member of an array exists in them.

For example, I am trying to find where one of these operators:
`char* Operators[2] = {"+", "-"};`

Would be in this string
`string check = "this+that";`

Comment: You can use `strstr()` to locate a substring within another string. If you have `char Operators[] = { '+', '-' }`, you could simply use `strchr()`.

Comment: I suggest you start by breaking this down into smaller steps. Describe in words the steps you would take to do this by hand.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Would I have to use a loop for each operator? and does ```strstr();``` return a position?

Comment: `size_t nstrings = sizeof Operators / sizeof *Operators;` then `for (size_t i = 0; i < nstrings; i++) { char *p = strstr (check, Operators[i]); if (p != NULL) printf ("Operators[%zu] contains %c\n", i, *p); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to check for a substring within a string, you want the `strstr()` function from `string.h`. The declaration is:

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

Where `haystack` is the full string (`check` in your case) and `needle` is the substring you want to find (the elements of `Operators` in your case). Since you have multiple substrings to test for, you will need to loop over each substring calling `strstr()` with each to check if that operator is found in `check`. You can do that simply with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    
    char *check = "this+that";                              /* pointer to string literal */
    char *Operators[] = {"+", "-"};                         /* array of pointers */
    size_t nstrings = sizeof Operators/sizeof *Operators;   /* no. of elements */
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nstrings; i++) {                 /* loop over each Operators */
        char *p = strstr (check, Operators[i]);             /* is it substring of check? */
        if (p != NULL)                                      /* if substring found */
            printf ("Operators[%zu] %c in check\n", i, *p); /* output result */
    }
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/operators
Operators[0] + in check
```